# query search letters to letters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, where-clause

I am making a search with suggestions offered on basis of letters typed in the search box.

**Example:**

> I have in database this words : `salam, salavat, sabos, sandal, sefid,
>   siah and ...`
>  I typed in search box : `s` --**display this
>   words**--> `salam, salavat, sabos, sandal, sefid, siah`
>  Now if
>   typed : `sa` --**display this words**--> `salam, salavat, sabos,
>   sandal,`
>  If typed : `sala` --**display this words**--> `salam,
>   salavat`
>  If typed : `salam` --**display this words**-->
>   `salam`

I am using jQuery event `.keyup()`(keyup is working fine) and using codeigniter at the backend(query in codeigniter not what that i want).

See my query(In this query, `$find` contains the sequence already typed in, and i am using `like` Keyword for searching in the database):

```
$find = $this->input->post('find');
    $where  =   "date LIKE '$find' OR
            name LIKE '$find' OR 
            star LIKE '$find' OR
            address LIKE '$find' OR
            number_phone LIKE '$find' OR 
            type LIKE '$find' OR
            service LIKE '$find' OR
            units LIKE '$find' OR
            useradmin LIKE '$find'";

$query = $data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
        FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        WHERE 
            $where
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT $offset, $coun_page       
        ) t,
        (SELECT @rownum:=0) r");
```

The following query works, but i can not use of it because of `rownum`:

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', $name)->get('my_table')
```

How do I get suggestions with `rownum`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For matching a substring with a `LIKE` query, you need to use a wildcard character, which in SQL is the percentage-character `%`.

E.g.

`WHERE foo LIKE '%bar%'` would find all rows where the column `foo` contains the substring `'bar'`.

`WHERE foo LIKE 'bar%'` would find all rows where the column `foo` begins with the substring `'bar'`.

`WHERE foo LIKE '%bar'` would find all rows where the column `foo` ends with the substring `'bar'`.

PS. it's always a good idea to contain column names in back ticks to avoid collisions with (potentially) reserved names, such as `date` and `type`.

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2` FROM `table` WHERE `column3` = 'value'
```

Comment: ok, tanks, now if have database words `nice car, nice, nice, nice car` and we searched word `nice`: how can **ORDER BY** (list) those like : `nice, nice, nice car, nice car` or if searched word `nice car` list like: `nice car, nice car, nice, nice` ?

Comment: Do not ask multiple questions in one question. When your original question is answered in a manner that satisfies you, close it (approve the correct answer) and ask follow up questions as new questions.